# Weird reference error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have the following code in a C# library:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace Gameloop.Util.Web
{
    public class QPayload : IDisposable
    {
        private byte[] _content;
        private Stream _stream;

        public readonly bool IsStream;

        public QPayload()
        {
            Content = new byte[0];
            IsStream = false;
        }

        public QPayload(byte[] bytes)
        {
            Content = bytes;
            IsStream = false;
        }

        public QPayload(string chars, Encoding encoding = null)
        {
            if (encoding == null)
                encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            Content = encoding.GetBytes(chars);
            IsStream = false;
        }

        public QPayload(Image image)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            image.Save(ms, image.RawFormat);
            Content = ms.ToArray();

            IsStream = false;
        }

        public QPayload(Stream stream, bool readNow = false)
        {
            if (readNow)
            {
                _content = ReadToEnd(stream);
                IsStream = false;
                return;
            }

            Stream = stream;
            IsStream = true;
        }

        public byte[] Content
        {
            get
            {
                if (_content != null)
                    return _content;

                return Content = ReadToEnd(_stream);
            }

            private set
            {
                _content = value ?? new byte[0];
            }
        }

        public Stream Stream
        {
            get
            {
                if (_stream != null)
                    return _stream;

                return Stream = new MemoryStream(Content);
            }

            private set
            {
                _stream = value ?? new MemoryStream(new byte[0]);
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Stream.Dispose();
        }

        public string AsString(Encoding encoding = null)
        {
            if (encoding == null)
                encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            return encoding.GetString(Content);
        }

        public Image AsImage()
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Content))
            {
                return Image.FromStream(ms);
            }
        }

        public static byte[] ReadToEnd(Stream stream)
        {
            using (stream)
            {
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    return memoryStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to use the following code in a project that uses this library, I get an error.

```
QPayload pay = new QPayload("text");
```

> The type 'System.Drawing.Image' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Drawing,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xyz'

I have many other classes in this library that use references like System.Web. When I use those classes however, I get no error asking me to reference System.Web and such.

Why am I being asked to reference a type that is only used by a reference?

Comment: Can you check the reference into the folder "References" of the project ? more specifiquely System.Drawing ? when this dll is located, can you check the version, it the version of the dll you load mathc woth the requested (Version=4.0.0.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `Image` directly in a constructor parameter. You have to have direct knowledge of System.Drawing.Image to use your class (even if you don't use that constructor). That's why VS wants you to add that reference, since otherwise you cannot use the constructor that takes an Image, since your calling code doesn't know about the `Image` class.

If, in the other classes, the using of `System.Web` stuff is 'inside', in other words, is not directly visible by the constructor(s), properties, methods, etc, then your using project doesn't need to know about `System.Web`. And therefore no mentioning by VS to add that reference.

Comment: How does `new QPayload("text")` use `Image` directly?

Comment: @Hele It doesn't but `public QPayload(Image image)` does.

Comment: @Hele You have a constructor `public QPayload(Image image)`.

Comment: Is there any way in which I could modify the above code so as to not require referencing it? (While keeping the functionality intact)

Comment: Yes, by removing the constructor `public QPayload(Image image) {}`, and the method `public Image AsImage() {}`. That is of course, the change needed for **this class**. If you have other classes that expose members that use `System.Drawing`, then you need to modify these as well.

Comment: I decided to do it by creating a QImagePayload class as a subclass of QPayload. This way, I can retain functionality while not needing the reference. Thanks for your answer =)